# CSV Trim rows from a string value and all values below it using python

Tags: python, csv

Python beginner here, I have a CSV file like so:

```
+---+-----+
|   |  0  |
+---+-----+
| 1 | abc |
+---+-----+
| 2 | def |
+---+-----+
| 3 | ghi |
+---+-----+
| 4 | jkl |
+---+-----+
| 5 | mno |
+---+-----+
```

and text file with a string value: `ghi`

I'm trying to search the csv file for the string in the text file and trim all the rows from that string's position in the csv file and all the rows below it.

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import csv


with open('a.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    ls=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
#print(ls)

with open('b.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for num, row in enumerate(reader):
        if ls in row[1]:
            placeholder = row[1]
            #print (row[1])
```

How can trim the rows in the if loop or should I go about another way to do this?

Comment: you could write another file, and break when you encounter the match

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up using lists and index to trim the list using the text as reference within the program, and dumping it into another csv file to get my desired output.